# Dividing a DafaFrame in spark to multiple DataFrames and writing to directories

Tags: scala, apache-spark

We would like to to write our data in a spark program to s3 in directories that represent our partitions.

Example: VisitFact DataFrame should be written to s3 and the partitions are date, hour, site and let's say that the specific Df has only one day (dt=2017-07-01), one hour (hh=02) and 2 sites (10, 11)
so directories would be:

- visits/dt=2017-07-01/hh=02/site_id=10
- visits/dt=2017-07-01/hh=02/site_id=11

We need to go over the dataframe and split it into the multiple df's (two in this case)

I would like this to be generic, so list of fields that define the partition can change and is of N elements

Does spark support this natively? What would be an efficient way to accomplish this
Thanks
Nir

Comment: Why do you need multiple Dataframes? Partitions are already written in that format. P.S. S3 doesn't have directories

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes spark supports partitioning

You  can use something like this

```
df.write.partitionBy("columns for partitioning").parquet("path to the top dir")
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will write all files in the same folder and we need each one to be in a different folder

Comment: This will write exactly how you want. This will write under same parent directory. For example  df.write.partitionBy("dt","hh","site_id").parquet("parent directort") will write the data exactly how you have mentioned. Incase you want more information please check this https://medium.com/towards-data-science/writing-into-dynamic-partitions-using-spark-2e2b818a007a

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with Nir go with partitions  choose between Hash Partitioning or 
Range Partitioning

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#bucketing-sorting-and-partitioning